# jquery select any dom element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to select any element (possibly on click) on page like body is selected, div is selected, div#foo etc... so i can place it to some variable and edit it later on.

i've tried

```
$("*", document.body).click(function (e) {  
 e.stopPropagation();  
 var domEl = $(this).get(0);  
 alert("Clicked on - " + domEl.tagName);  
});
```

but it's not working for all elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the [`target`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) property of the event:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   var domEl = e.target; // or $(e.target) to jQuerytize it
   alert("Clicked on - " + domEl.tagName);
});
```

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/dyHEA/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
    $("*").click(function () {
         console.log($(this));
         return false;
        }
    ); 
});
```

Comment: This is a very, very bad way to solve the issue, it'll attach a click handler to every element in the page.

Comment: I agree, though is what he asked, to select any element on the page.